# ManagementObjectSearcher.Get() throws exception

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, system.diagnostics, system.management

When executing the following code, the `searcher.Get()` throws an exception "Not Supported".  Even when running as admin the problem persists.  This is compiled with VS 2010.  The exception happens on XP, Win7 and Win8.1.  Any ideas??

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName");
 foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
 {
 }
```

Comment: In the machine where the exception is raised exists at least one COM port installed?

Comment: Why would you downvote this question??

Comment: The comments suggest that there is a WMI query that would detect the presence of serial ports in a safe way before this query gives their names. Someone want to do some research and provide a nice answer?